# Database value Send to Javascript using PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How send value from php which i get from database. The value that is send should look like in"[.....]".

```
var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can encode them like this and use them in javascript.

```
$sth = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```